# problem in executing shell script

Tags: shell, unix

i am new to shell scripting. My objective is to execute the ls command through a shell script but it does not return anything. Mine is a BASH shell

```
set p = `/bin/ls`
echo $p
```

Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For bash the way to do it is

```
p="$(/bin/ls)"
# Could have done p=`/bin/ls` too, but $( is the newer way
echo "$p"
```

The `set` command is not for standard variable assignment.

Answer (score 4):

A simple

```
p=`/bin/ls`
```

will suffice although I prefer the `$()` construct since it's easily nestable:

```
pax$ p=$(/bin/ls)

pax$ echo $p
clients.dat clientupdate.sh
```

What your `set` does (after processing all the valid switches to set shell attributes, of which there are none) is to assign the parameters to the `$n` arguments:

```
pax$ set p = `/bin/ls`

pax $ echo xx $1 xx $2 xx $3 xx $4 xx $5
xx p xx = xx clients.dat xx clientupdate.sh xx xx
```

From the `man bash_builtins` page:

> Any arguments remaining after the options are processed are treated as values for the positional parameters and are assigned, in order, to `$1, $2, ... $n`.

Answer (score 0):

The Bash syntax is to not put in spaces when assigning values to variables, so do it like this:

```
p=`/bin/ls`
echo $p
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just write...

```
/bin/ls
```

...in one line?